# Lose histories when copying directory from repo1 to rep2 with Git

Tags: git, git-history

I must to copy a directory from repo1 to repo2 using Git with all histories.
The steps are :

```
git clone <git repository A url>
cd <git repository A directory>
git remote rm origin
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <directory 1> -- --all
mkdir <directory 1>
mv * <directory 1>
git add .
git commit
git clone <git repository B url>

cd <git repository B directory>
git remote add repo-A-branch <git repository A directory>
git pull repo-A-branch master --allow-unrelated-histories
git remote rm repo-A-branch
```

The problem that with `--allow-unrelated-histories` just a last commit saved.

I want to save all hostories.

Any ideas ?

Comment: "with --allow-unrelated-histories just a last commit saved".  That's not how --allow-unrelated-histories works.  Please show the observed symptom that leads you to believe there's a problem.

Comment: When comparing histories of my directory in repo2 with direcory in repo1, i have a difference. Just the last commit or in some file, the last two or thre saved. I followed this URL (https://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/)

Comment: Directory history output is simplified by default; what you're describing is inconclusive.  Beyond that, as I said you need to *show* (not describe) the symptom.  That means in the question, you need an update with the exact command, exact resulting output, and how you expect that output to be different.